# Cant find a OpenCV header file (CMake, OpenCV4, C++)

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

When I am creating custom libraries using OpenCV4 in the libs directory I am getting the following error:

```
/Documents/opencv-palisade/libs/image.cpp:2:10: fatal error: opencv2/opencv.hpp: No such file or directory
        2 | #include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
          |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Directory Structure:

```
.
├── build
│   ├── CMakeCache.txt
│   ├── CMakeFiles
│   ├── cmake_install.cmake
│   ├── image.jpg
│   ├── include
│   ├── libs
│   ├── Makefile
│   ├── opencv-palisade
│   ├── test.jpg
│   └── transformed_image.jpg
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── libs
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── image.cpp
│   └── image.hpp
└── main.cpp

5 directories, 12 files
```

libs/CMakeLists.txt:

```
project(libs)
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_library(
      image_compute
      SHARED
      image.hpp
      image.cpp
)
```

root CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16.3)
project(opencv-palisade VERSION 1.0)

#Include header files
add_subdirectory(libs)
include_directories(libs)

  
# Import OpenCV library
find_package(OpenCV 4 REQUIRED)
if(OpenCV_FOUND)
  message(STATUS "Found OpenCV version ${OpenCV_VERSION}")
  message(STATUS "OpenCV directories: ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
  message(STATUS "OpenCV libraries: ${OpenCV_LIBS}")
  include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
else()
  message(FATAL_ERROR "OpenCV not found, please read the README.md")
endif(OpenCV_FOUND)
  
#build main.cpp  
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)
target_link_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC libs)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${OpenCV_LIBS} image_compute)
```

How can I fix this issue to be able to create libraries using opencv api?

Comment: You call `add_subdirectory(libs)` **before** `find_package(OpenCV 4 REQUIRED)`, so variables like `OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS` are not defined when CMake parses `libs/CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: Ah yeah I get you now. It now works after changing it thanks!